# SOLID principles while creating objects

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles

Here's the scenario:

> A User can create shapes using a form.
>
> User will select from a list of options of shapes (circle, square, rectangle and so on) and submit the form by clicking on create shape button.
>
> The shape he created will be linked to his account.

Here's how I'm approaching it:

An Interface `Shape` with a method signature to `create()` a shape, which will be implemented by individual shape classes.

```
# Shape.php
interface Shape {
    public function create();
    public function area();
}

# Rectangle.php
class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private $user;
    private $data; # user submitted data

    public __construct($user, $data) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function create() {

        # get rectangle shape details from RectangleShapeAPI

        $userShape = new UserShape; # the model to store data
        $userShape->shape_id = $this->data['shape_id'];
        $userShape->area = $this->area();
        $userShape->users_id = $user->id;

        # save rectangle shape details from API

        if (!$userShape->save()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function area() {
        return $this->data['length'] * $this->data['breadth'];
    }
}
```

Now, I've to `switch($shapeType)` over the shape type selected by the user to instantiate the `Square` or `Circle` or `Rectangle` classes appropriately.

```
$data = $_POST;
switch($shapeType) {
    case 'square':
        Shape $shape = new Square($user, $data);
        $shape->create();
    break;

    and so on...

}
```

> This is my first step towards implementing `SOLID Principles` and I
>   think I may have gotten it wrong. Please forgive me in that case.
>
> The **problem** is I think the switch statement (I've seen examples
>   where people try to eliminate `switch` or `conditions` when they try
>   to use those objects). I've seen this only at the time of using the
>   objects which I think is possible very easily. But can we achieve the
>   same during the time of object creation (I am not able to find any
>   logical solution to this other than `switch`ing over shapes).
>
> Other thing is, how to handle the `$_POST` data effectively as the
>   keys to the array may change in future and anything may happen. How
>   would you handle this scenario?

---

The above explanation is the simplified version of my case.

I have an `Accounts` Interface with `add()` method that is implemented by `FacebookAccount`, `GoogleAccount` and other classes.

Now the methods to `add()` these accounts are different, hence used as an interface. The `Facebook` or `Google` api objects are created and user data is fetched to store into `UserAccount`. The accounts are linked to the user.

---

I welcome all those who wants to give me their way towards approaching this problem using SOLID Principles. I will be very thankful to all and hope I will learn a lot of things about the principles and what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT**

Link to SOLID Principles: [SOLID Principles Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: Can you please include a link to the SOLID Princpiples above? In your case i would implement an abstract Shape class and do the stuff, that is commen to all Shapes there to avoid redundancy.

Comment: I've included the link. I could have too, but the `create()` method has to call some external api to get some data and store with the `UserShape` object. The functionality of `create()` differs between shape. Or in my case the functionality differs between accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came up with solutions to both problems.

**The switch problem**

Create a factory class that will return the required object. This will hide the conditional complexity of retrieving an object from the scene.

**The `$_POST` data problem**

This was actually quite easy and is common sense to pass the data to the `create` method instead of passing to the constructor. Passing the data to the `create` method solves this issue as the method only deals with creating new object and the other parts of class are now independent of that change.